# Is there away to combine group_by with mutate from R to Python with Pandas

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert the following block of codes written in R to Python:

```
 df <- df %>% 
  group_by("column_1") %>%
  mutate(new_col1 = length(which(column_x < 1)),
  new_col2 = new_col1 /counter)
```

```
df: is a dataframe
```

My attempt to do this in Python is the following blocks:

```
df = df.groupby(['column_1']).apply(
new_col1=len(df[df['column_x']] < 1)),
new_col2= df['new_col1'] / num_samples)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
```

Note that column new_col2 needs new_col1 to be created and so I couldn't find a way to combine the operation of creating two columns with custom behavior and group them by a single column from the data frame.

How would I able to convert the above R block of codes into a working python code using pandas?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: kindly add sample data with expected output

Comment: Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. Only plot images are okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we do `transform`

```
df['new_col1'] = (df['column_x'] < 1).groupby(df['column_1']).transform('sum')
df['new_col2'] = df['new_col1']/num_samples
```

`dplyr::mutate` here is equal to `transform`, but transform only accept one column calculation

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It did work, a very clean and straightforward code answer, love it.

Comment: @aBiologist yw :-) happy coding

Comment: @aBiologist also , if this is what you need, would you like accept it ?